# 500 Internal server error in admin login On magento

Tags: magento

In magento site i cant to access the admin panel.

When i taking admin panel it displays error in fire bug:

```
"NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://192.168.1.100/magento_upgrade/admin"



The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must to be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol.
```

How can i solve this issue?

Comment: Do you have some errors in your error.log?

Comment: how can i check erro in error.log

Comment: And don't which webserver you use. Bit in your apache folder there should be a log/error.log.

Comment: we dont have access for the webserver.

Comment: ok this is a problem. The most providers to a log file in a seperate folder on your webspace.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14502/discussion-between-mariya-davis-and-stony)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We discussed it in chat. But i had the same problem before a few month. The system was working on my local mashine but not on my webserver.

This was because i my FTP-Client (FileZilla) changed the Encoding of the files and after that i got an 500 error. When you google for that problem you cannot find any solution. But i think there are wrong rights. Or there is something changed during the upload.

I have made a zip file and extract them over ssh on my server. This is a problem when you don't have some **SSH** access.

http://trac.filezilla-project.org/ticket/2830

And there are some settings in FileZilla that can cause some problems. Unter **"Settings -> Transfer -> filter for illegal characters"** i hope its correct my client is in german disable this filter.

"Edit: Ok the curl module was not installed"